# Smart way of doing scalar product

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have a question about how to do a scalar product. So I have $m$ vectors of length $n$ (we will refer to a such vector as $a$). Furthermore I have a matrix $B$ that is $n\times n$ and that does not change at all. I want to calculate the following quantity:

$$a_1(a_1B_{11}+...+a_nB_{1n}) + ... + a_n(a_1B_{n1}+...+a_nB_{nn})$$

(There will be $n$ terms, $a_1(a_1B_{11}+...+a_nB_{1n})$ is the first term.)

I would like to know if there is a way I can calculate this in $O(n)$ time. For example if we removed the $a$'s before the parentheses, we would have:

$$(a_1B_{11}+...+a_nB_{1n}) + ... + (a_1B_{n1}+...+a_nB_{nn})=a_1(B_{11}+...+B_{n1}) + ... + a_n(B_{1n}+...+B_{nn})$$

And we could simply calculate $(B_{11}+...+B_{n1})$ beforehand and then have a vector of these quantities that we could do a scalar product with $a$ then.

Let me know if this does not make sense, then I will be happy to try and elaborate!

Looking forward to your answers!

EDIT: My matrix $B$ is symmetric does that somehow help with what I seek? And thanks so for the swift feedback!

Comment: The result is $\sum_{i,j}a_ia_jB_{ij}$. Each $B_{i,j}$ has to be read and used in the formula. There are $n^2$ of them.

Comment: One thing that works for some problems is to change coordinates such that the new matrix $B$ becomes diagonal and do all computations in the new coordinates.

Comment: @logarithm but doing as you advise, each time you have a vector $A$, you have to convert it into the new basis... therefore no gain.

Comment: @JeanMarie That depends on the problem. If the place where all evaluations occur in the problem can be interpreted in the new coordinates, then one only perform them there and only the input has to be converted to the new coordinates, and the solution. For example, a root finding, or an optimization, which require many evaluations of the quadratic form can be done entirely in the new coordinates without any reference to what are the coordinates of the points in the original system. The bulk of the points involved are not important, only the solution is needed in the original coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your problem amounts to evaluate efficiently a quadratic expression (mathematics keyword : "quadratic form"):

$$Q=A^TBA$$

(where $A$ has entries $a_i$) which could, in a certain sense be called a "generalized dot product".

There is no general trick.

But if your matrix has a particular property, you can improve the efficiency. For example if $B$ is **symmetric positive definite**, you can do - once for all because you say $B$ is fixed - a so-called "Cholesky factorization" $B=C^TC$ where $C$ is upper triangular.

See for that https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/04/15/efficient-quadratic-form.html

**Complexity analysis in the case of Cholesky factorisation $B=C^TC$:**

For each new $A$, compute $D=CA$ (an $O(n^2)$ operation), then compute $Q:=\|D\|^2=(CA)^T CA$ which is $O(n)$. Finally, it's still a $O(n^2)$ algorithm, but more efficient than the direct calculation (the number of multiplications and additions is approximately halved).

---

Edit : I have seen what you wrote about "removal of the $a_i$s in front of the parentheses" but it will never be possible to assume that.

Comment: No reaction to this answer ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, but thanks this is very nice answer!